# sqlplus command not found after installing oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have going at it for the last 12 hours... I installed Oracle 12c on rhel7, the first installation didn’t go well so Installed a second one without changing the first installation; I created a new folder and proceeded with the installation. However I have not been able to connect to the database in anyway. When I try the command: `env|grep -i ORACLE_HOME` I get : `ORACLE_HOME= /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2/spfileorcl.ora`. Can you suggest a solution on how to setup my `environment variable` based on the configurations in the picture? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/christian/app/christian/product/12.1.0/dbhome_2
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

Alternatively:

```
. oraenv
```

And provide `orcl` as `ORACLE_SID`.